# html keycodes not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code:

```
function noNumbers(e)
{
    var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : 
                 ((e.charCode) ? e.charCode : 
                   ((e.keyCode) ? e.keyCode : 0));
    if((charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && (charCode > 45 || charCode < 47))
        e.preventDefault();
}
```

The objective is to make it so that users can type numbers, the backspace key, and the delete key. It works in Chrome and IE, but in firefox, you can just type the numbers,not the backspace or delete keys however.

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sdy9gd0g/

Comment: Here's the JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sdy9gd0g/

Comment: Still doesn't work in firefox. In fact, doing that, breaks it for chrome and IE the same way.

Comment: I do not want the user to be able to type the letter.

Comment: [Like so](https://jsfiddle.net/ufuafkd5/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me on Firefox.

```js
var keycodes = {
    'backspace': 8,
    'delete': 46,
    'leftArrow': 37,
    'rightArrow': 39,
    'number1': 48,
    'number9': 57
};

function noNumbers(e)
{
    var charCode = e.which ? e.which : 
                 (e.charCode ? e.charCode : 
                   (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : 0));
    
    if ((charCode < keycodes.number1 || charCode > keycodes.number9) &&
        charCode !== keycodes.delete &&
        charCode !== keycodes.backspace &&
        charCode !== keycodes.leftArrow &&
        charCode !== keycodes.rightArrow)
        e.preventDefault();
}

document.getElementById('noNum').addEventListener(
 'keypress', noNumbers
);
```

```html
<input id="noNum">
```

Comment: Works perfectly for me in all 3 browsers, Thanks!

Comment: Although I'm not allowed to tell you exactly why this is allowed in this instance, we want users to input data correctly the first time, and if they paste in data different from the expected data, they are at a loss.

Answer (score 5):

Why not handle the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event instead? This method will handle live changes via keyboard entry, cut, paste, etc.

```js
(function() {
  var textBox = document.getElementById("text-box");
  textBox.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    var val = this.value,
      rx = /[^\d]/g;
    if (rx.test(val)) {
      var pos = this.selectionStart;
      this.value = val.replace(rx, "");
      this.selectionStart = pos;
      this.selectionEnd = pos - 1;
    }
  });
})();
```

```html
<input id="text-box" autofocus>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply add `console.log(e);` in your function and debug what's going on:

Chrome/IE doesn't call this function on `Backspace` and `Delete` key press. Firefox logs `keypress { target: <input#noNum>, key: "Backspace", charCode: 0, keyCode: 8 }` and `keypress { target: <input#noNum>, key: "Delete", charCode: 0, keyCode: 46 }` respectively. So there is two solutions:

1) Add `if` for these `keyCode`s (8 and 46)

2) Do not use `keypress` event and use `keydown` instead (as @Teemu wrote).